# MVC Razor using CheckBoxFor within for loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My view Model:

```
public class SendFileDeviceViewModel
  {
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string ManagementGroupName { get; set; }
    public int ManagementGroupId { get; set; }
  }

  public class SendFileManagementGroupViewModel
  {
    public string ThisManagementGroupName { get; set; }
    public List<SendFileDeviceViewModel> DeviceList { get; set; }
  }
```

My View:

```
@model Ceridian.Wfm.DeviceManager.Models.Terminals.SendFileManagementGroupViewModel
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = "~/Areas/Terminals/Views/Shared/Master/_TerminalLayout.cshtml";
}
@section termimalContent {


  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    foreach (var dev in Model.DeviceList)
    {


    <fieldset>
        <legend>@dev.DeviceName - [ @dev.ManagementGroupName ]</legend>

          @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.

        </fieldset>
    }
    }
  }
```

The lambda returns my whole model, rather than the contents of `dev`. Can anyoen help please

Comment: Yes. Use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => dev.`.

Comment: Thankyou Zabavsky, found answer by searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found this on SO

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => dev.reloadConfiguration)
```